# error realmjs requires a node package manager (n or nvm). when run-ios react native

Tags: react-native

I use realm in react native and when build on mac I have this error:

```
RealmJS requires a node package manager (n or nvm).
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer [`nodenv`](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv). It works the exact same way as [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), if you're familiar with that. *But*, `realm` wants either `n` or `nvm`, which I think isn't fair. It should just want and expect *a* version of `node`. Not any, or worse a specific, node package manager.

Answer (score 0):

whenever this error occurs it means node version and react-native versions are not compatible with realms database version and error like
1-RealmJS requires a node package manager (n or nvm).
  Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 
2-PhaseScriptExecution missing script files related to realms etc occurs 
**So**, to resolve this uninstall realm and re-install it with different realm version. There is no need to touch node, react-native etc.